# Implement __contains__ method on class object

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

I am trying to write a class whose main purpose is encapsulation and I want it to be single instance.

```
class ACN(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_acn_certs(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def get_suppporting_cert(cls, domains):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def __contains__(cls, item):
        return True    
3 in ACN
```

When i run the above script it gives the following error on last line. 
How can I implement `__contains__` method here

> ```
> 3 in ACN TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magicmethods are only looked up on the object's class (declaring them as classmethods doesn't change anything here), so when you're doing `3 in ACN`, python searches for a `__contains__` (or `__getitem__`) method on the class of `ACN` (the metaclass), which is the builtin `type` class. If you want to use the ACN class as an instance AND use magicmethods, you have to use a custom metaclass and define the magicmethods on it:

```
class ACNType(type):
    def __contains__(cls, item):
        return True   


class ACN(metaclass=ACNType):
   # your other methods here
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, clearly and concisely explained.  Clarification:  Would it not make sense to name the first arg "self"?  Even though the value is a class, it's still an instance of the metaclass, and the convention is to use "self" in the definition of instance-level magic methods.

Answer (score 1):

the command '3 in ACN' will not work because you have declared a class but did not make an instance of it.
If you want to create a class that will be a single instance, I invite you to read a bit about the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
Here's some more info for [Singleton pattern on python](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html).
Then, you wil be able to use a method like 'get_instance()' into a local variable and use it.
When you make an object from a class it automatically inherits the Object class and has a **contains** method. I would love to understand better why you need it?